# What is the best way to build an Exchange 2010 CAS based on an existing production server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, exchange, exchange-2010

We have a CAS + Hub server in our organization right now. We want to create a second one with the exact same settings and features.

What would be the best approach to do this?

We have been looking into SCCM but it would take us some time before we could purchase the license for it and deploy it.

Comment: I don't suppose you have meticulous documentation of how the first one was installed?

Comment: Whatever you do - do not clone it (as in copying the entire server - popular method with virtual servers).

Comment: @ChrisS unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloning is not the way to go, due to the configuration of Exchange being stored within active directory.  Luckily, meticulous documentation is probably not required.

I know it may not be the answer you're after, but seeing as you're only adding a second CAS+HUB, simply installing server (2008 R2 I assume?) takes about 30 mins, put the SP on (another 30 mins?) and all the WUs (a good while, but its easy!) and installing Exchange (not too long, < 1 hour) may be the most time efficient way to do it.

The CAS and HUB roles will pick up the policies from the domain.  The only real things you've got to do is setup your IP addresses and virtual directories.

However, as you're adding a second CAS, I am going to assume some form of NLB which is the biggest thing to do here as this may affect both the new, and the old CAS.  Not something SCCM could have solved anyway - always a manual approach and planning required.

So in summary, do it manually.. it's not actually as bad as you think it is, because most of the config is stored in AD and it'll pick it up.

Comment: It's one now but let's say it's five tomorrow. These will go behind a hardware load balancer. Was hoping for an elegant partially automated way to do this. In Linux, I'd use cobbler and puppet to deploy another cluster node.

Comment: Both Windows Server and Exchange Server setup can be automated with answer files. If you know there will be demand for these in the future then put the time into setting up a Windows Deployment Services infrastructure (with WAIK for extra functionality) to deploy the machines. [Exchange Server 2010 unattended setup](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997281(v=exchg.141).aspx). [Windows Automated Install Kit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748933(v=WS.10).aspx).

Comment: @GreenstoneWalker that's a great answer! Wish you would have submitted before deadline.